# How the best methodology to create an .NET client application supporting plugins?

Tags: .net, plugins, add-on

I found the .net plugin architeture very complex to use as plugin platform. I think that an plugin interface needs be simple to 3rd coders develop with.

Do you know/use/etc some plugin techinique more simple and effective? To be more exact, let's imagine that we will develop a text editor like notepad, that needs (by example) plugins for different syntax highlighiting, interface changes, shell integration, etc.

Do you will use the built in .net plugin code, or will build/use some different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a looksie at [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF). It's designed exactly for this and it's very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Any IoC framework + some dynamic assembly loading.